# Error 1004 VBA : How to set text of shapes that are in range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set **text of shapes that are in range of cells**.
In the below code I loop through shapes in my `activesheet`, if the range given `masqueA` intersect with `topleftcell` then `select` this shape and set text of this `selection`.

```
Sub numShape()

Dim masqueA As Range
Set masqueA = Range("b33:l42")
cpt = 1

For Each shapeTemp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(Range("masqueA"), shapeTemp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        shapeTemp.Select
        Selection.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "cpt"
        cpt = cpt + 1
    End If
Next shapeTemp

End Sub
```

However I have this error : `Run-Time error'1004' : Application-defined or object-defined error`

Does someone can explain to me why I have this error and how to fix it.
By the way is my code doing what I trying to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please always tell us the line that generates the error. There are dozens of possibilities where that error *could* occur. Having to guess doesn't make it easier on the folks answering. That said, what is the purpose of `cpt`? Do you want each shape to say exactly `cpt`, or do you want them to say `"1", "2", "3", ...`?

Comment: Yes indeed I want the shape to say 1,2,3...
It does show where the error is generated or I don't know where to look at.

Comment: In this case you'll want to do `Selection.TextFrame.Characters.Text = """" & cpt & """"` (that's 4 quotes each, if you want the quotes to show. Otherwise it's just `.Text = cpt`).

Comment: Regarding the error, that's slightly confusing. What happens when you Compile the project (from the Debug menu)?

Comment: It seems the error is at this line : `Set Range("b33:l42").Name = masqueA`

Comment: That's not from the code in your question. And it can't work that way. The `.Name` property expects a string and you want to assign an object to it. Where does that line come from?

Comment: Well I just realised I didn't understand well the answer below from @TinMan. I understand now what he meant.

Comment: @Inarion I corrected it. Sorry for all this mistakes. I have linked this to a button to trigger this method. However it still run into an error : `property or method not managed by this object`. I used the debugged tools but nothing shows up.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52760647/edit) your question to reflect your changes.

Comment: @Inarion I solved my problem finally. I was executing this in the wrong worksheet. Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`masqueA` is a Range and not a Defined Name.  If you want to refer to a range by name then use `Range("b33:l42").Name = "masqueA"` and `Range("masqueA")` as is just use `Intersect(masqueA, shapeTemp.TopLeftCell)`.

```
Sub numShape()

    Dim masqueA As Range
    Set masqueA = Range("b33:l42")
    cpt = 1

    For Each shapeTemp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(masqueA, shapeTemp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "cpt"
            cpt = cpt + 1
        End If
    Next shapeTemp

End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I made the changes as you suggested. However I still have the same error.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening.  There is no reason to select the shape.  I modified my answer.  If you link me the workbook, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for removing the `Select`. :)